# EPPlus multiple saves

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus library in `asp.net + C#` to create `.xlsx` file. My file may contain a few million records and i'm creating one `ExcelWorksheet` per 100K records. problem is that a `40Mb` xlsx that contains almost `1.5M` records my take multiple Gbs of main memory and after that i get an `OutOfMemoryException`, question is:
How can i reduce memory taken `X Gb for 40M?`:-| or save `ExcelPackage` gradually and deallocate memory, (it seems that i can not save more than once and after that whole package is disposed).

If there is no solution, can anybody introduce a alternative for EPPlus (with almost all features like styling, worksheets and etc)

Comment: No answer after a week?

Comment: This is a very common issue. EPPLus is a great library but when it comes to writing large files, memory consumption is a huge issue :(

Comment: Do you know any good alternative for .Net?

Comment: For those people who are now seeing this question, you should know that EPPlus has version 4.0 in Beta testing, which takes care of a lot of the speed issues. Take a look at epplus.codeplex.com

Comment: @user1202498, You can look into [Openxml SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407(v=office.12).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue seems to be solved in the latest version of EPPlus (4.0.x)

---

EDIT: Adding reference links to pages which point to improved memory management in EPPlus 4.0.4.

https://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/118053#ReviewsAnchor
**Reviews by users about improved memory performance in 4.x version as compared to 3.x version**.

https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap
Version 4.0: New cellstore to improve insert, delete performance **and memory consumption**

This link explains how to ensure that loading HUGE number of cells is optimized.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation
Refer section "I have a lot of data I want to load. What should I think of to get the best performance?"

Also, I've personally tested EPPlus 4.0.4 today, by writing out 1.5 Million records  at one go, of 5 numeric rows and 1 DateTime row, and the peak memory working set reported by Windows Task Manager was just 711 MB. The Non-Paged Pool shown by Windows Task Manager was just 75K or so!  Of course, I'm not sure whether these numbers capture the full impact of the memory footprint, but these are indicative. The output Excel file was around 59MB (might be that my columns were more than the sample data mentioned by you in your original post.)

**NOTE: I did get an "OutOfMemoryException" when I tried to write 4.5 Million records of 7 columns in one go!**

Is my test rigorous enough? Maybe not...Works well for me though.

---

However, one workaround I could think of to overcome the large memory requirements in earlier versions is to split and save an xlsx file for every 100K records. After saving, start using a new file (with appropriate file name counter increment) for the next 100K records.

At the end of your operation, you'd end up having 10 files of 100K records for say a total of 1 million records.

Might seem a bit of a hack, but hey, might be better than having to rewrite your code base to use some other library (free or commercial).

Comment: I've used this workaround before asking question. It works, but not the best answer. May you provider exact link to the solved issue or page that has described the new feature? then I'll mark you as best answer

Comment: thank you for the upvote, and also for the "mark as best answer"... Due to your vote, I'm now finally able to do all the basic activities in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 5):

**Multiple saves will not help.** If you try to save and close the file in the middle of your export process, then invoke garbage collection, you will see, that consumed memory will be freed. But if you then will try to open the file again, the same amount of memory will be consumed by the process. And if you try to continue your export processing, you will fall into the same problem again.

**AFAIK all modern .NET libraries based on Open XML SDK perform processing in memory**. So do EpPlus. **The only way is to perform processing on hard disk without loading into memory.**

Comment: Your answer is rational and correct. but I can't accept this answer because my main question is still unanswered, "Is there any alternatives?"